# Gtk::GLAreaで描画がされない

Tags: c++, opengl, gtk

GtkmmのGLAreaを使用してOpenGLによるグラフィックスプログラミングを行おうとしているのですが、glBegin〜glEndやglDraw*を呼び出しても内容が描かれません。glfwを使って同じコードで描画した場合には描画されるにもかかわらず、Gtkmmを用いた場合にはDrawCallが無視されているようです。以下が問題のコードです。

```cpp
std::vector<glm::vec2> vtx {
            { 0, 1 },
            { -1, -1 },
            { 1, -1 }
};
const char* vertex_source =
            "#version 460"
            ""
            "in vec2 position;"
            ""
            "void main() {"
            "   gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);"
            "}";
const char* fragment_source =
            "#version 460"
            ""
            "out vec4 outColor;"
            ""
            "void main() {"
            "   outColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);"
            "}";

class canvas : public Gtk::GLArea {
public:
    canvas() {

    }
    void on_realize() override {
        Widget::on_realize();

        make_current();

        //create shader
        shader = glCreateProgram();
        //attach vertex and fragment shaders

        //create buffer
        glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
        //glBindBuffer, glBufferData 

        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    }
    void on_unrealize() override {
        Widget::on_unrealize();

        //destroy buffer and shader
    }
    bool on_render(const Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::GLContext>&) override {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glUseProgram(shader);
        glBindBuffer(vbo);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glUseProgram(0);
        glFlush();
    }
private:
    GLuint shader;
    GLuint vbo;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv);
    Gtk::Window window;
    window.set_default_size(1000, 700);
    canvas cv;
    window.add(cv);
    window.show_all_children();

    return app->run(window);
}
```

上記のコードでglDraw*は無視されるのですが、glClearColorで設定した色で背景は塗りつぶされるようです。
期待する動作は黒の背景に白の大きな三角形が描かれることですが、どのようにすれば描画されるようになるでしょうか。

環境はUbuntu18.04、Gtkmm 3.22.2です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

OpenGLは2.0相当のものしかやったことがないのでアレですけど。

```cpp
const char* vertex_source =
            "#version 460"
            ""
            "layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;"
            ""
            "void main() {"
            "   gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);"
            "}";
```

でないでしょうか。

`glEnableVertexAttribArray`関数などで指定するattribute変数のローケーションですが、
明示的に指定しなけれれば何番にロケーションされるは定かではありません。
なので、(OpenGL3.0以降であれば)シェーダ内でlayout修飾子で明示的に指定するか、`glBindAttribLocation`関数で明示的に指定するか、`glGetAttribLocation`関数で何番にロケーションされたか調査しなければなりません。

- 参考: [layout 修飾子によるロケーション指定](https://wgld.org/d/webgl2/w004.html)

Comment: glGetAttribLocationで確認した上で明示的に指定しなかったのですが、layout修飾子で明示的に指定しても同じように何も表示されませんでした。

Comment: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkGLArea.html#GtkGLArea.description、https://github.com/GNOME/gtkmm/blob/master/demos/gtk-demo/example_glarea.cc等を参考にコードを書いていて、これらと同じようにしているので特にこれといった意図はありません。glewを使った場合にはコンテキストを作成した後にglewInitを呼び出す必要があるのでその順番に従っている、というのがあります。

Comment: あ、realizeシグナルに対するコメントですか？すいません、まぁ問題ないだろうなぁ、と思って消してしまいました。

Comment: glewでちょっと気になったのですが、set_required_versionメソッドでバージョンを指定してみてはいかがですか？ https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1GLArea.html#a1f6a4da0d66461b5a89abbb784dc2ab9

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。set_require_versionでバージョンを指定してみても結局変わらず何も表示されないままでした。やはりOpenGLでのコーディングミスというよりはGtkによる特殊な条件でこの問題が起きているというような気がします。https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668041/gtkglarea-clears-background-but-does-not-draw?noredirect=1&lq=1　同様の問題が他でも起こっているようです。